# Javascript : Chrome capabilities for "default download directory", "download.prompt_for_download", and "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally"

Tags: javascript

want to know how to set below capabilities of chrome in javascript. I know Java and python but want in javascript.

Javascript : Chrome capabilities

1. "default download directory"
2. "download.prompt_for_download"
3. "download.directory_upgrade"
4. "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally"

python code

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "C:/Users/517/Download", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome 
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

If possible provide link where I can refer for javascript.

Comment: I don't think JavaScript can configure these options itself, except maybe in an extension.

Comment: JS can't control browser. But if you are running tests, then e.g. in Selenium you can do https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/chrome-options#nodejs

Comment: Have got api-doc link but want how include same `https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [api-docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html), I am able to set capabilities in Javascript except default download path. However, same can be achieved by `await wdriver.setDownloadPath('C:\\Downloads');`

```
var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

let downloadFilepath = "C:\\Downloads";
let options = await new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments('--ignore-certificate-errors');
options.addArguments('--ignore-ssl-errors');
options.setUserPreferences({'download.default_directory': "C:\\Downloads"});
options.setUserPreferences({'download.prompt_for_download': false});
options.setUserPreferences({'download.directory_upgrade': true});
options.setUserPreferences({'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': true});

driver = await chrome.Driver.createSession(options);
```

Let me know if "download.default_directory" can be set using capabilities instead of `wdriver.setDownloadPath`.